# When multiplying fractions by whole numbers, what is the correct way to write the operator?

Tags: notation, fractions

I am currently working through an assignment and one of the parts of my solutions is to multiply $\frac{3}{64}$ by three. The assignment is much more complex than that, don't worry! But in thinking about how to write this in LaTeX, it inspired another question.

I've looked up previous questions and I have found two solutions - either $\frac{3}{64}\cdot3$ or $\frac{3}{64}\times3$ will do the job. However, the answers for these questions don't really go over *why and when* to use $\cdot$ and $\times$. In this case, what would the correct operator be? In addition - and more generally - where would each symbol be mostly used and why?

Comment: Both are correct.  You'd also be fine with $(\frac3{64})(3)$.  Symbols for multiplication are generally used to prevent ambiguity, and after that it becomes a stylistic choice.

Comment: So for an example like this, the choice between the dot operator and times symbol is mostly just personal preference?

Comment: Yes, absolutely!

Comment: Ok, that's perfect for this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Both of those symbols are used very generally for multiplication between numerical constants.  For multiplication between more complicated things (such as vectors, functions, or sets), you sometimes have to be careful about which symbols to use and when.  But not here.

Comment: It is worth mentioning as well that in more exotic contexts, there may be many different types of "multiplication" (*hadamard product, inner product, cross product for vectors for instance*).  While $\cdot$ and $\times$ are generally reserved for the most common of the multiplications available to a particular context, if you wish to talk about an uncommon or nonstandard multiplication, you have available symbols such as `\odot,\otimes,\boxdot,\boxtimes` making $\odot,\otimes,\boxdot,\boxtimes$ respectively or similar in order to emphasize they are unusual multiplications.